# Is taking sum inside cross product valid?

Tags: summation, vectors, cross-product

I have a sum of a cross product over one of the multipliers. In this case it has a physics application being a sum over magnetic moments, $\vec{\mu}$, to give magnetisation, $\vec{M} = \sum_i\vec{\mu}_i$. What I'm doing is this
$$ \sum_i \left(\vec{\mu}_i \times \vec{B}\right) = \vec{M} \times \vec{B}\,, $$
where $\vec{B}$ is the magnetic field and is taken to be independent of $i$. I just wanted to double check that taking the sum inside the cross product to replace the sum of $\vec{\mu_i}$ with $\vec{M}$ is valid?

Comment: Yes, because cross product is distributive

Comment: Ah right thanks, that's what I thought but I get especially wary of cross products for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cross product is distributive, meaning that for any three vectors $\vec{x},\vec y,\vec z$, you have

$$(\vec x + \vec y)\times \vec z = (\vec x\times \vec z) + (\vec y\times\vec z)$$

This naturally extends to any finite number of vectors (you can prove this by induction), so if you have $\vec{x_1},\dots \vec{x_n}, \vec y$, you have

$$\sum_{i=1}^n(\vec{x_i}\times \vec y) = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \vec{x_i}\right)\times \vec y$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes it clear, I figured it would be some simple property of the cross product but I wasn't 100% sure